# Correct way to retry messages in batch in case of error in Spring Integration using ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice

Tags: spring-integration

I am processing messages from batch.

Defined `advice` for `MessageHandler`

```
ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
advice.setFailureChannelName("errorChannel");
```

Once there is an error processing one or more messages from they payload,  `serviceActivator` is triggered

```
 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
 public void handleFailure (Message<?> message){
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException adviceException = (ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException) message.getPayload();
    //throw CustomException
```

So the above gives me the error but not which item from payload caused it (can be more than one).

What is the correct way to retry the payload(one by one)?

Should I somehow 'Split' the payload ?  if yes what is the way to do this.

I tried replacing

```
 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
 public void handleFailure (Message<?> message){
```

with

```
  @Splitter(inputChannel = "errorChannel", outputChannel = "outboundChannel")
 public List<Message<?>> handleFailure2(Message<?> message)
```

But couldn't split the messages from there as message's type is `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException`

Answer (score 0):

Spring Integration deals with a `Message` as a unit of work. It doesn't matter for the framework if payload is a batch of data or not: the service throws an exception, the whole failed message is sent to the error channel with a single exception.

You may consider to use an `AggregateMessageDeliveryException` in your service to gather all the errors in a single exception and then throw it for processing in that error handler. There you can inspect such an aggregate to determine what items in batch have been failed.

If you'd like to go a splitter way, then it is going to be a general splitter for your batch and then you process in your service items one by one. Not sure if that is what you'd like to do. However splitter can be configured for an `ExecutorChannel` as an output to process items in parallel.

Comment: Why can't I just define splitter with input=errorChannel, so failed batch will go there, and output of splitter will handle messages one by one

Comment: Because the input for your `errorChannel` is an `ErrorMessage` with an `Exception` as a payload which is not splittable. Yes, you can write some splitter function to produce a list or stream even against that `Exception`, but your question is how to know which items have failed.

Comment: let me rephrase, as am I writing to database - it's all or nothing when talking in batch. So I would like to just iterate all message and send them one by one to output channel (JDBC)

Comment: So, you should use a single transaction and really retry the whole batch. Not sure then why do we talk about splitting in case of error...

Comment: batch is not good, as probably one specific message causes the issue, so I want to retry one by one if batch fails

Comment: OK. Then you indeed have to gather all the errors and split them in the error flow. Then you can send failed items back to the input for retries. You might build a new batch from that error handler to retry as a single message.

Comment: can I use ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvicefor that purpose e.g. as error handler? because I tried that and got some strange outcome

Comment: See its `trapException` property. Even if you send an error message, the exception is still thrown back to the caller.

Comment: well most of the expected errors, I ignore anyway - so no issues with trapping exception.

Comment: I would still recommend to do that. In my understanding you'd like to catch an exception in that service, send an `ErrorMessage` into that `errorChannel` flow. Do some processing and retry in the end back to this service. So, it is better to not re-throw that exception back to the caller.

Comment: I just don't want to send them all they way back to the source of the flow, limit them to MessageHandlers the actually handles them.

Comment: Sure! Feel free to send them whatever place is appropriate! The error flow is just a flow, so whatever routing and processing is there in the framework is possible in the error flow.